# Do the subjects of verbs such as "watch," "listen for," and "read" stand for agents, experiencers, both, or something else?

Tags: syntax, semantics, argument, semantic-roles

**one:**    It’s well-known that the subjects of different verbs in different contexts can take subjects that have different semantic roles.

For example, in the sentence “Jill ate a hamburger,” “Jill” stands for an agent.
But in the sentence “Jill saw a nice sunset,” “Jill” stands for an experiencer.

**two**:    The subjects of the following sentences stand for experiencers as well.

“Jack smelled smoke.”
“The dog heard a loud noise.”
“Henry felt the cold air.”

**three**:    QUESTION:    Are the subjects of the following sentences agents, experiencers, both, or something else?

“Lily watched ants for fun.”
“Jack was reading the book.”
“The boy listened for the train.”